# Sharing assemblies using Portable Class Library with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8, data-annotations, portable-class-library

I have created a portable class library called `DataContracts` that contains my projects `Messages` and `Views`. Standard stuff like `GetStockItemByIDRequest` and `StockView` are contained in it.

The problem lies when I attempt to add `DataAnnotations` by using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for some of my `Views` as such.

```
[DataContract]
public class StockView
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid StockID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can successfully add the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to my Portable Class Library project and can successfully reference it in my Windows Phone 8 app and can even create a new instance of my view as such `StockView View = new StockView();` within my Windows Phone App BUT if I try to use either `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` by doing something like

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://myservice.com");
T result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
```

OR

```
T result = await Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>("{}");
```

ie: where deserialization is involved...

I am faced with the error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=2.0.5.0'`. Which I assume is because it doesn't appear that `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` [is supported in Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (but then why can I add it as a reference to my PCL?).

So my questions are, why isn't this error invoked when I create a new instance of these classes directly and secondly how do I work around this?

Comment: Custom Attributes are not in the process of create a new class instance.

Comment: Ok fair enough but then what is the correct approach to avoid this problem. Surely others have tried to create cross project compatible Portable Class Libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that my original assumptions were completely wrong. You absolutely can reference the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace from a Windows Phone 8 project.

Basically it comes down to counterintuatively referencing the silverlight version of the dll which can be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`

For more information about how to build portable class libraries I suggest [referring to this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx) .

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately DataAnnotations is not currently portable.  While a bit complicated, you can probably work around that by writing your own DataAnnotation attributes in a PCL, and creating an assembly with the same name for .NET Framework projects which type-forwards the attributes to the "real" versions.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046668/1509) for some more details on this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the answer but it appears that there is a portable version of the DataAnnotations attributes that can be referenced via the Silverlight assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Data annotations is supported in certain PCL profiles.

Supported profiles:

- .NET 4.0.3 and up
- Windows Store 8 and up
- Silverlight 4 and up

Most notably, the latest Windows Phone is not supported (8.1 at the time).

See full PCL feature table in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why on earth do Microsoft insist on making these things so obscured on their own platforms?

Answer (score 0):

1) The process of create a new class instance doesn't involve read custom attributes, that are loaded by reflection.

2) The [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is exclusive for ASP.NET

> The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace provides attribute
>   classes that are used to define metadata for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET
>   data controls.

Comment: Cheers for the first insight but System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is not just for ASP.NET. It is also widely used in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The portable version of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations seems incomplete (eg no MaxLengthAttribute).

There is this library:

https://github.com/ryanhorath/PortableDataAnnotations:

```
Install-Package Portable.DataAnnotations
```

Your PCL needs to target Silverlight 8, otherwise you will get multiple class definition errors.