# DataAnnotation Name class to be serialised

Tags: data-annotations, asp.net-web-api, portable-class-library

Is it possible to name the class/ViewModel for a WebAPI response object using [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or is there an alternative;

```
//[DataMember(Name="CarDepot")] -- this doesn't work
//[Display(Name = "CarDepot")] -- this doesn't work
public partial class CarDepotVM
{
    [Display(Name = "CarDepotVM")]
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}
```

The library which contains the following code is PCL complaint, therefore I cannot use any external libraries which aren't compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way I can implement IValidatableObject on Portable Class Library Project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023742/is-there-any-way-i-can-implement-ivalidatableobject-on-portable-class-library-pr)